# Can't echo out user data on home page

Tags: php

This is the code for my function

```
 public function getuserData() {
  session_start();
  $username = $_SESSION['user']; 
  $getData = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
  $getData->bindParam(1, $username);
  $getData->execute();
  $row= $getData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $email = $row['email'];
  $user = $row['username'];
  echo $email. '<br />';
  echo $user;
}

<?php

require_once "class/user.php";

echo $user;
echo $email;


$object = new User();
$object->getUserData();

?>
```

and here is my home.php, the username, and email echo out but only from the function, if i try to do echo `$email;` on the home.php it doesn't print. I need to print it out on the home page so  I can style the output.

Already tried starting session on `home.php` and it still doesn't work, as I already started it in the `getUserData()` function.

Comment: Your function is called `getuserData()`, and you're calling `getUserData()` on the homepage. Notice the capitalization of the `u`.

Comment: oops, changed fixed it, it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those variables are only in the scope of the function itself, if you want to access that information, you'd have to return the values from the function.

user.php

```
public function getUserData() {
  session_start();
  $username = $_SESSION['user']; 
  $getData = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
  $getData->bindParam(1, $username);
  $getData->execute();
  $row= $getData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return $row;
}
```

home.php

```
<?php

require_once "class/user.php";

$object = new User();
$userInfo = $object->getUserData();

echo $userInfo['username'] . '<br>';
echo $userInfo['email];
```